# Удалить символы из файла при помощи Python?

Tags: python

У меня есть файл `rich.txt`, который преимущественно выглядит как словарь, где каждая строка начинается новым словом. К сожалению, после каждого слова следует символ `/` и несколько букв, от которых мне нужно избавиться.
Выглядит это так: (каждое слово начинается с новой строки)

```
Äbte/Nm
Äbtissin/Fm
Äbtissinnenliste/Nm
Äbtissinnenstäbe/Nm
```

Нужно добиться:

```
Äbtissin
Äbtissinnenliste
Äbtissinnenstäbe
```

Так как файл достаточно большой, удалить это вручную нереально. Поэтому, мне бы хотелось при помощи регулярного выражения `(\/)\w*` удалить эти символы после всех слов при помощи Python и сохранить изменения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе ваши попытки решения. На данном ресурсе принято помогать тем, кто сам что-то попытался сделать)

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/

Comment: регулярку составьте, и в тех строках, что встретились эти символы, меняйте их на пустые символы

Comment: У меня получилось убрать ненужные символы, вернее заменить их:          import re
worte = '''Äbte/Nm 
Äbtissin/Fm 
Äbtissinnenliste/Nm
Äbtissinnenstäbe/Nm
'''
f = re.sub(r'(/)\w*',' ',worte)
print(f)                                                                                                                            Однако так как я новичок в Python я запуталась в том, как я могу сделать это в самом файле и после этого сохранить эти изменения

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

В данном простом случае можно обойтись без регулярных выражений:

```
with open(r"C:\Temp\rich.txt", encoding="utf-8") as fin, \
     open(r"C:\Temp\result.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as fout:
     for line in fin:
         s,_,_ = line.partition("/")
         print(s, file=fout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь https://regex101.com/ 
Если у вас есть нужное регулярное выражение, протестируйте его на нужной строке(в вашем случае текстом из файла или хотя бы частью). Если все заработает как задумано, просто выберите нужный язык и вам сгенерирует код для вставки. Его и используйте

```
import re

regex = r"(\/)\w*"

test_str = "do/asdsa"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Можно также настроить тонко поиск. (игнорирование перенос и т.п.)
Если вы правда хотите научиться, то вот: https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/